# Send notification with condition

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a user table in leave web like these

```
id |    name        |      email         |  pic  |  email   | team  | level 
1     Michael         michael@mic.com        4                  1     staff
2     John Doe        john.doe@gmail.com     4                  1      staff
3     Kelme           kelme@gmail.com        5                  1     staff
4     Munich          x.munich@det.com               yes        1     manager
5     Phylon          phy@phylon.com                 yes        1    manager
```

In these table, user id 4 and 5 is manager from user id 1,2 and 3. I want to set 
1. if user id 4 and 5 want to receive email notification, then if user id 1,2 or 3 sent leave request, they received it in email and when login to application
2. If user id 4 or user id 5 want to receive email notification, the email will sent to user id 4 or 5 that want it and they can login to application to see it
3. If they are both don't want to receive email notification, they will not have email request from their staff, but they can login to application to see it

I have tried it but I'm still confusing how to fulfill 3 condition above, it's not working at all

here's the code

```
    $first = Users::where('id',$id)->first();

    $sender = Users::where('id',$first->pic)->where('team', $first->team)->get();

    $finals = Users::where('id',$first->pic)->get();
    if($first->level!='user')
    {
        $sender = Users::where('level','manager')->where('team', $first->team)->get();
    }
    foreach ($sender as $send)
    {
        $to[]=$send->id;

    }
    $check = Users::whereIn('id',$to)->get();
        foreach ($check as $ch)
        {
            $cha[]=$ch->email;
            if($cha=='no')
            {
                return redirect ('index');
            }
            if($cha=='yes')
            {
               $data = array('name' => "Gorgon");

               Mail::send(['text' => 'mail'], $data, function ($message) {
               $message->to('mail1@xxxx.com', 'Tutorials Point')->subject('Laravel Basic Testing Mail');
               $message->from('notif@xxxx.com', 'Gorgon');
    });
            }

        }
```

Comment: "In these table, user id 4 and 5 is manager from user id 1,2 and 3. I want to set 1. if user id 4 and 5 want to receive email notification, then if user id 1,2 or 3 sent leave request, they received it in email. 2. If user id 4 or user id 5 want to receive email notification, the email will sent to user id 4 or 5 that want it. 3. If they are both don't want to receive email notification, they will not have email request from their staff." I really don't want to be that guy, but I don't understand what it is you said here... What's the problem exactly? People getting emails when they shouldn't?

Comment: Hi @Loek, no, the case if I as a manager don't want to receive email notification, I just updated on database on notification to be no, so I will not receive email, just login to application.